# MPMusicPlayerController with AirPlay?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, airplay, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am creating an audio app which uses iPod Music Player, I need Airplay functionality.
I also used RoutePlayButton in `MPVolumeView` slider. I don't have apple TV to test if it will work or not.

```
    MPVolumeView *myVolumeView;
    [myVolumeView setShowsRouteButton:YES];
```

1.) How can we add Airplay functionality to MPMusicPlayerController?

2.) How can we test the Airplay feature from the app, on which devices?

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.) To add Airplay functionality to MPMusicPlayerController**

```
MPVolumeView *myVolumeView;
    [myVolumeView setShowsRouteButton:YES];
```

**2.) To test airplay without Apple T.V.**

[AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/) is a paid app.
I tried the trial version, it was working fine on Mac-Mini. Please let me know if anyone come across any free app. As @Prince suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps you check airplay without apple TV in iMac.

1) Download [AirPlayer 0.28 beta](http://download.cnet.com/AirPlayer/3000-13632_4-75330532.html) application then install it. `AirPlayer` transform your Mac into an `AirPlay-compatible display`.

2) Now go to `System Perferences` and in there is select `Sharing`.

3) Tick `internet Sharing` by making `WiFi On`.

**EDIT** : 4) Make `WIFI` `ON` in device also

4) Now open `AirPlayer 0.28` app and `play` `video` in `app`.

5) You will see `airplay button` in `MPVolumeView` as it will `display` names of `devices` which can `support` `airplay` and `select` your `mac` for `airplay`.

You r done. Enjoy........

Comment: Make WIFI ON in device also. check answer again

Comment: You could also try Reflector or AirServer apps.

Comment: +1 Prince, thanks for support. I dont know why AirPlayer was not running  on my mac mini, Hope for other users it may work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to install Airserver on your mini mac.
2. Soon you installed and made your Airserver activated then your device shows airplay symbol.
3. Choose your mini mac from the list and rest of the things you can see on your mini mac.

For installing trail version of Airserver you can go through this link:

http://www.airserver.com/Download/

You no need to code anything for airplay. Just the thing is your mini mac should have airplay option enabled (If not Airserver) and by default airplay is set to YES.